# duplicate multi column entries postgresql

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have a bunch of data in a postgresql database. I think that two keys should form a unique pair,
so want to enforce that in the database. I try

```
create unique index key1_key2_idx on table(key1,key2)
```

but that fails, telling me that I have duplicate entries.

How do I find these duplicate entries so I can delete them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you only want to delete the duplicates and keep the original, the accepted answer is inaccurate -- it'll delete your originals as well and only keep records that have one entry from the start. This works on 9.x:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE ctid IN 
(SELECT ctid FROM 
  (SELECT ctid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (partition BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY ctid) AS rnum 
  FROM tblname) t
WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates

Answer (score 29):

```
select key1,key2,count(*)
from table
group by key1,key2
having count(*) > 1
order by 3 desc;
```

The critical part of the query to determine the duplicates is `having count(*) > 1`.

There are a whole bunch of neat tricks at the following link, including some examples of removing duplicates: [http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Delete_duplicate_rows_with_window_analytic_functions)

Comment: Be aware that some of the info on that wiki is *very* outdated, though. Double check with the official documentation when it says something in Pg behaves a certain way or that you can't do a certain thing.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is accurate. This will result in you dropping the originals as well -- not just the dups. IE, if you have 2 entries of the same column set, this select will match/drop both of them -- not only the dups. Sure you'll satisfy the constraint -- but you also just lost valid data (any entries with more than 1 copy will be lost entirely).

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.*
from tbl a
inner join tbl b on (
a.id <> b.id
and b.col1 = a.col1
and b.col2 = a.col2
)
order by a.col1 asc
```